# Is it okay to have a HTTP Post Request that passes in parameters with the URL, and also passes in a body?

Tags: http, url, http-post

Is this against the rules? Will one of the things passed in be ignored? Is there a standard that most people have gravitated to?

Answer (score 0):

No it is not against the rules.  A web framework should not ignore either piece of information.  There is no standard that defines how to do this as far as I know.

In fact there is a [specification](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-nottingham-uri-get-off-my-lawn-01) currently being written that says, in essence, that no-one should write application level specifications that constrain URIs.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I have a follow up question: If I am making an application that creates a generic HTTP request and accepts user input necessary information, for example, the parameters that are passed in on an HTTP Post, is it a bad idea to always take those parameters and pass them in with the body? According to the specification, this should be okay because every web service that a user should be accessing should accept parameters through both the body and the URI. But what about the few that don't? Should I code around this issue, or is the web service's responsibility to adapt?